# Cell data getting cropped for particular table layout. iText 2.1.7

Tags: java, itext, tablelayout

For particular table layout with particular cell having larger data then it is not getting properly exported to PDF, the data in that particular cell getting cropped.

```
private static void tableLayout1() {
    Document doc = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(
                ".\\TableLayout_1.pdf"));
        doc.open();

        // Table
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
        table.setSplitLate(false);

        //row 1
        PdfPCell cell00 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell00"));
        cell00.setBackgroundColor(new Color(200, 0, 0));
        cell00.setRowspan(3);
        PdfPCell cell01 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell01"));
        cell01.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 200, 0));
        cell01.setColspan(2);

        //row 2
        PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell11"));
        cell11.setBackgroundColor(new Color(100, 100, 0));
        PdfPCell cell12 = new PdfPCell( getLongCellData() );
        cell12.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 200, 200));
        cell12.setRowspan(2);

        //row 3
        PdfPCell cell21 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell21"));
        cell21.setBackgroundColor(new Color(200, 0, 200));

        table.addCell(cell00);
        table.addCell(cell01);
        table.addCell(cell11);
        table.addCell(cell12);
        table.addCell(cell21);

        doc.add(table);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    doc.close();

}

private static Paragraph getLongCellData() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sb.append("Cell12_" + i);
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    return new Paragraph(sb.toString());
}
```

Here the data from cell12 (which has row span of 2 and has larger data) is getting cropped at the page end and it is not being continued on next page. 
Tried dividing this table into two different tables as below, but still the issue is there.

```
private static void tableLayout2() {
    Document doc = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(
                ".\\TableLayout_2.pdf"));
        doc.open();

        // Table
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
        table.setSplitLate(false);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 2});


        //Inner table for column 1
        PdfPTable column1Table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell00 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell00"));
        cell00.setBackgroundColor(new Color(200, 0, 0));
        //cell00.setRowspan(3);
        column1Table.addCell(cell00);


        //Inner table for column 2 
        PdfPTable column2Table = new PdfPTable(2);

        PdfPCell cell01 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell01"));
        cell01.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 200, 0));
        cell01.setColspan(2);

        PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell11"));
        cell11.setBackgroundColor(new Color(100, 100, 0));
        PdfPCell cell12 = new PdfPCell( getLongCellData() );
        cell12.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 200, 200));
        cell12.setRowspan(2);

        PdfPCell cell21 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell21"));
        cell21.setBackgroundColor(new Color(200, 0, 200));

        column2Table.addCell(cell01);
        column2Table.addCell(cell11);
        column2Table.addCell(cell12);
        column2Table.addCell(cell21);

        table.addCell(column1Table);
        table.addCell(column2Table);

        doc.add(table);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    doc.close();

}
```

This issue is partially resolved on iText5, but, due to some issues upgrading library is not quite possible for us, so is there any solution for this ?

With iText5 the data is not getting cropped but cells' heights are not so appropriate. For TableLayout_2_withIText5.pdf cell21 should have rendered on page3 instead of page4. For TableLayout_1_withIText5.pdf cell21 is getting extended in the margin area of Page1.

Comment: The solution is to fix the "some issues" that are preventing you from upgrading to iText 5. Because, if it doesn't work in iText 2, but it does work in iText 5, then it was probably a bug or a missing feature in iText 2, and it has been solved in iText 5. I can imagine that you don't like this answer but I don't think anyone will spend any time on this question when you yourself already acknowledge that it works in a newer version.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thank you for the response. Yes, I can understand this must be bug on iText2. but, just wanted to know anybody has any workaround for this layout, as this is quite simple layout and chances are that someone else might have encountered this before.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Sorry I didn't mention it initially as I was seeking solution for iText2.1.7 specifically, but just thought to inform you that, this issue has not been completely resolved on iText5. Please check the last statements of question I have just edited.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Well, iText 2 and iText 5 are both end of life. Does it work with iText 7?

Comment: Yes, it does work with iText7.

Comment: In that case, problem solved?

Comment: I can upgrade library in our next product release, but, right now I will have to find some workaround as I am providing patch for our older release.
 Like iText 2.1.7 does not support a table cell having both rowspan and colspan. So, I am dividing such table into multiple tables, so that columns can be combined avoiding colspan. 
So, looking if someone has tried any such tweak or know any property which can make this work.